# Are questions about Google / PageRank allowed on Pro Webmasters?

Tags: discussion

The title pretty much sums it up. Is this the right stack exchange site for a question about SEO / Page Rank / changes to Google's algorithm? If not, what is the right place?

Answer (score 5):

You are in the right place. We already have had a lot of questions about [SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo), [Google](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google), and [PageRank](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pagerank) so be sure to read up on those first. Then if you still have question we will be here to (hopefully) answer them for you.